# How to populate text fields when radio button is clicked?

Tags: php, text, radio-button, echo

I am creating a web page where there are two divs (billing details and shipping details). When the page is loaded, the billing details are automatically displayed and the shipping details remain empty. I have included two radio buttons which allows the user to choose whether or not the shipping details are the same as the billing details. If the user selects yes from the radio buttons then the same details should be displayed in the shipping details.
Note: the details are stored in database are am using php to get the data displayed

At the moment, I have only tried using

```
<?php if(isset($_POST'[shipping'] == 'yes')){echo $fname} ?>
```

on the first name field just to see if it is working, but i doesnt seem to work.

```
<div id="leftprofile">
    <form id="au" method="post" action="../../../coursework/coursework/scripts/checkout.php">
    <fieldset class="billing">
        <legend>Billing Details</legend><br />
        <label for="fname" class="reglabel">First Name:</label>
        <input required name="fname" type="text" id="fname" value="<?php echo $fname ?>"/><br />
        <label for="lname" class="reglabel">Last Name:</label>
        <input required name="lname" type="text" id="lname" value="<?php echo $lname ?>"/><br />
        <label for="address" class="reglabel">Address:</label>
        <input required name="address" id="address" type="text" value="<?php echo $address ?>"/><br />
        <label for="town" class="reglabel">Town:</label>
        <input required name="town" id="town" type="text" value="<?php echo $town ?>"/><br />
        <label for="postcode" class="reglabel">Post Code:</label>
        <input required name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text" value="<?php echo $postcode ?>"/><br />
        <label for="phone" class="reglabel">Phone:</label>
        <input required name="phone" id="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $phone ?>"/><br />
        <label for="email" id="EmailLabel" class="reglabel">E-mail:</label>
        <input required name="email" type="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"/><br />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="rightprofile">
    <form id="au" method="post" action="../../../coursework/coursework/scripts/checkout.php">
    <fieldset class="billing">
        <legend>Shipping Details</legend><br />
        <form>
            Same as billing address?
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" id="yes" value="yes">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" id="no" value="no">No<br/>
        </form>
        <label for="fname" class="reglabel">First Name:</label>
        <input required name="fname" type="text" id="fname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST'[shipping'] == 'yes')){echo $fname} ?>"/><br />
        <label for="lname" class="reglabel">Last Name:</label>
        <input required name="lname" type="text" id="lname" /><br />
        <label for="address" class="reglabel">Address:</label>
        <input required name="address" id="address" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="town" class="reglabel">Town:</label>
        <input required name="town" id="town" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="postcode" class="reglabel">Post Code:</label>
        <input required name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="phone" class="reglabel">Phone:</label>
        <input required name="phone" id="phone" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="email" id="EmailLabel" class="reglabel">E-mail:</label>
        <input required name="email" type="email" id="email" /><br />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, the names of the inputs on both the billing and shipping or the same, so you'll run in to problems when you finally do get the form submitted.  Also, this would need to be done in Javascript, since it would need to be handled before the form is submitted. (also should be noted, only one form can be submitted at a time, where as now you have two separate forms for both submitting to the same location.)

Comment: they are different divs but the text fields are the same

Comment: Exactly my point. If all will be submitted to the same `action`, you need to distinguish between the billing and shipping fields `name`'s.

Comment: For one, Jon is right, you need unique names. Two, jesus h christ it was the first google result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192836/copy-billing-and-shipping-address-fields-copy-to-another

Comment: As far as I understand the concept of what you are trying to make I believe it would be best suited with using only one form, instead of two. I also see that the `action` URL are the same, so it seems natural to merge these two forms into one single form. As Jon pointed out, all the `name` attributes in the `<input>` fields will need to be unique, so that you can fetch the appropriate data in the PHP script.

Comment: Also. You do not necessarily need to use Javascript to "copy" the billing address to the shipping address. You could run a check for the radiobox, and if it is true, then use the same information from billing as in shipping.

Answer (score 1):

I have written you some simplified example code. This site contains one form, with two input fields (billing and shipping), and one checkbox to check if the shipping information is the same as the billing information. If the checkbox is checked the code will simply ignore anything typed into 'shipping'.

This would achieve what you are asking for, at least from a PHP perspective. If you are looking more for the "copy the data in those input fields, to those input fields" in real time in the browser, then that is a task for Javascript, and not PHP.

```
<?php
/* Check if anything was submitted */
if(isset($_POST))
{
    /* Retrieve billing information */
    $billing_name = $_POST['billing_name'];
    $billing_addr = $_POST['billing_addr'];

    /* Check if shipping same as billing */
    if(isset($_POST['same']))
    {
        /* Shipping is the same as billing */
        $shipping_name = $billing_name;
        $shipping_addr = $billing_addr;
    }
    /* If not, set shipping to the posted value */
    else
    {
        $shipping_name = $_POST['shipping_name'];
        $shipping_addr = $_POST['shipping_addr'];
    }

    $insert = mysql_query(...);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="#" />

Billing information
<label for="billing_name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="billing_name" name="billing_name" />
<label for="billing_addr">Addr</label>
<input type="text" id="billing_addr" name="billing_addr" />

<label for="same" />Is the shipping information the same as billing information?</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" />

Shipping information
<label for="shipping_name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="shipping_name" name="shipping_name" />
<label for="shipping_addr">Addr</label>
<input type="text" id="shipping_addr" name="shipping_addr" />

<input type="submit" value="Register" />

</form>
```